# Visual Studio 2015 extension method call as method group

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, extension-methods, method-group

I have an extension method like

```
public static void RemoveDetail<TMaster, TChild>(this TMaster master, TChild child)
        where TMaster : class, IMaster<TChild>
        where TChild : class, IDetail<TMaster>;
```

And I have two classes

```
public class Principal : IMaster<Permission>
{
        public virtual IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; }
}
```

and

```
public class Permission : IDetail<Principal>
```

I call **RemoveDetail** from an Action accepted by method `public static void Foreach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action);`:

```
aPrincipal.Permissions.Foreach(x => aPrincipal.RemoveDetail(x));
```

ReSharper suggest me to replace this call with method group like

```
aPrincipal.Permissions.Foreach(aPrincipal.RemoveDetail);
```

This worked fine in VS2013 and previous but it fails on compilation in VS2015 with

> 'Principal' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveDetail' and no extension method 'RemoveDetail' accepting a first argument of type 'Principal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anyone has a suggestion? 
Do I have to update all of the usages and make ReSharper to avoid this replacement?

Comment: This is supposed to work. The C# Language Specification says this shall work.

Comment: it compiles in my VS 2015

Comment: Stupid question, but is your project targeting the correct version of the framework?

Comment: Please post a *complete* example. I can't reproduce this either using `List<T>.ForEach`. What is the type of `z`? Are you sure you aren't missing a reference or a `static` keyword somewhere?

Comment: updated to more specific usage

Comment: @3dd I didn't update target Framework. It was .Net 4 in VS13 and it is still 4

Comment: Upvoted because this question possibly found a bug in VS2015 compiler, I just wish it was asked in a better way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem

```
public interface IDetail<T>
{

}

public interface IMaster<T>
{

}

public class MyClass
{
    public void method()
    {
        Principal aPrincipal = new Principal();
        aPrincipal.Permissions.Foreach(x => aPrincipal.RemoveDetail(x)); // No suggestion from resharper
    }
}

public class Permission : IDetail<Principal>
{

}

public class Principal : IMaster<Permission>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; }
}

public static class Class
{
    public static void RemoveDetail<TMaster, TChild>(this TMaster master, TChild child)
        where TMaster : class, IMaster<TChild>
        where TChild : class, IDetail<TMaster>
    {

    }

    public static void Foreach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {

    }
}
```

The resharper does not suggest anything. so probably you have to update your Resharper to newer version. probably was a bug which is fixed now.

If this is not like the way you do. then you have to put more information.

Also Compiler gives same error when i try to convert it to method group. So this question may remain: **Why Compiler cant do this?**

**Edit:**

To fix this problem you have to call the `RemoveDetail` method from inside Principal. so make your Principal class like this.

```
public class Principal : IMaster<Permission>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; }

    public void RemoveDetail(Permission p)
    {
        Class.RemoveDetail(this, p);
    }
}
```

I think there is kind of ambiguous inside compiler (Possibly bug) that cant recognize `RemoveDetail` method. how ever compiler tries to find it inside `Principal`. so you can fix it with creating `RemoveDetail` inside `Principal` and call a static `RemoveDetail` from there.

**Edit 2:**

The problem is generic type constraint.

```
where TMaster : class, IMaster<TChild>
```

This makes compiler to look at class which implements `IMaster<TChild>` and thats `Principal`. if you remove this where clause it will solve the problem. otherwise the compiler expects that it should be `Principal`.

If you use lambda you remove this ambiguity.

```
aPrincipal.RemoveDetail // compiler expects property/field/method in Principal
                        // but compiler forgets method group and static generic method!
x => aPrincipal.RemoveDetail(x) // this is no more like property or field
                                //but a method that is considered static generic method!
```

So thats a C#6 bug

Comment: If I replace `x => aPrincipal.RemoveDetail(x)` in above code with just `aPrincipal.RemoveDetail` it compiles under VS2013, C# 5.0, targeting .NET 4.5.2. Can anyone confirm that this will not compile under the new C# compiler?

Comment: I tested in Visual studio 2015. C# 6.0, targeting .NET 4.6 and it does not work with `aPrincipal.RemoveDetail` @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: I confirm the first form does compile, but the second form does not compile in VS2015 on 4.5.2. BTW if I comment out `where TMaster : class, IMaster<TChild>` from RemoveDetail method, it compiles fine. I guess they changed the way extensions are inferred for method group.

Comment: There must be a bug in the new C# compiler!

Comment: In the ***C# Language Specification***, the section (section no. 6.6 in my version) _Method group conversions_ of the chapter _Conversions_ makes it very clear that an extension method can be found from a method group in this way. So this is required to work.

Comment: I contacted Eric Lippert and asked him to have a loo at this thread.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Does Eric Lippert have anything to do with the C# compiler any more?

Comment: Note that `public virtual IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; }` is an auto-property without a `set` accessor. This is allowed in C# 6.0 only. If you want to try the above example under C# 5.0 or earlier, try e.g. to say `{ get; set; }` instead, to make that part compile.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i have found the problem. its bug in C#6. see the new edit

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary thank you for the answer! That is exact what I have. Sorry for an odd way of asking, just my first time.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen this is not auto-property, I just extracted it from metadata. Actually the property has backing field

Comment: I do not have C# 6.0 here. Can you call the extension method in an ordinary way. I.e. can you say `aPrincipal.RemoveDetail(new Permission());` in the bottom of the body of `method` method above?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes you can but it's not a method group

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary just updated to Resharper 9.2 and it's the same. Switched off **convert lambda expression to method group** in Code Inspection | Inspection Severity as there is no other way

Comment: i have resharper 9.1.1. i will upgrade it and let you know the behavior. probably resharper got the bug again! i did not changed the options. and resharper suggests convert if i remove the where clause. @dvas_dubna

Comment: @dvas_dubna i dont know why but resharper still does not suggest anything for me.how ever i hope this bug is reported and they will fix it soon.

Comment: I have entered the example in dotnetfiddle.net. C# 6.0 (roslyn 1.0.0-rc): https://dotnetfiddle.net/6VjBpk and C# 5.0: https://dotnetfiddle.net/245npq but both examples show the same behavior.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It does work on `Mono v3.10.0` : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php .how ever this does not compile with only getter property. but both your tests are working with only getter property. probably its a bug inside update on both versions C#6 and C#5.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a feedback on this subject to Microsoft on September the 3rd 2015 here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1747835/visual-studio-2015-extension-method-call-as-method-group

Today I got this feedback from Neal [MSFT]:

> This is fixed in VS2015 Update 1.
>   It is tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4970

Answer (score -2):

I don't see how it worked in VS2013.  `RemoveDetail` is a method of `TMethod` not your Action `MyClass`.

It should be something like

```
z.ForEach(x => master.RemoveDetail(x);
```

Comment: Yes it does. The extension method essentially works for any `object` as there is no constraint to the generic type `TMaster`. The compiler succesfully resolves `TMaster` to `MyClass`.

Comment: full signature is 
`public static void RemoveDetail<TMaster, TChild>(this TMaster master, TChild child)
            where TMaster : class, IMaster<TChild>
            where TChild : class, IDetail<TMaster>;`
**this** here is an instance of master class, so it owrks

Comment: @dvas_dubna Does `MyClass` implement `IMaster<TChild>`?

Comment: @dvas_dubna please post an complete example that *does* reproduce the problem. As others noted, the (incomplete) code you provided compiles just fine in 2015 once some typos are fixed

Comment: @InBetween: I am assuming that `MyClass` does **NOT** implement `IMaster<TChild>` and stand by my answer.

Comment: @RichardSchneider The code compiles. If `TMaster` has no constraint then *any* object is a valid choice: `public static Foo<T>(this T obj)` will succesfully resolve to any `T`. Can you find a type for `T` that will not compile succesfully? The signature originally posted by the OP is essentially the same..

Comment: @InBetween But OP says `TMaster` has constraint `class, IMaster<TChild>`.

Comment: @RichardSchneider That information was initially brought up by the OP in comments to your answer so how did you manage to know about this before answering? We got ourselves a time travel riddle here.

Comment: @InBetween It was just an assumption.  I've seen this master/child pattern in may places.